# VS2015 builds project without errors, CSC has error CS1545

Tags: visual-studio-2015, csc

I have a c# console application that listens for the NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged event:

```
using System;  
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;  

namespace NetworkingConnectivityTest  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged;  

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");  
                Console.ReadKey();  

                NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged -= NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged;  
            }  
            catch ( SystemException e )  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine( "Main() exception: " + e.Message );  
            }  
        }  

        private static void NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged( object sender )  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                ConnectionProfile inetCp = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();  
                Console.WriteLine( "network information changed - internet connection profile: " + inetCp.ProfileName );  
            }  
            catch ( SystemException e )  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine( "NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged exception: " + e.Message );  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

When I build it in VS2015 (Debug or Release) code builds and runs as expected.

When I build it with VS2015 Development tools command prompt like so:
csc /nologo /noconfig /warn:4 ..\program.cs ^
    /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll" ^
    /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll" ^
    /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.1\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" ^
    /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd"

I get these 2 error messages:
f:\test\networkingConnectivityTest\program.cs(12,36): error CS1545: Property, indexer, or event 'NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'NetworkInformation.add_NetworkStatusChanged(NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler)' or 'NetworkInformation.remove_NetworkStatusChanged(EventRegistrationToken)'
f:\test\networkingConnectivityTest\program.cs(17,36): error CS1545: Property, indexer, or event 'NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'NetworkInformation.add_NetworkStatusChanged(NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler)' or 'NetworkInformation.remove_NetworkStatusChanged(EventRegistrationToken)'

Any help greatly appreciated - thanks in advance.

Comment: EventRegistrationToken is a WinRT implementation detail, the compiler has no clue that you are trying to target WinRT types.  A console project normally doesn't either, you have to doctor the .csproj file by hand to get it to compile.  Discover the proper incantation by looking at the CSC.exe command that MSBuild uses when you build in the IDE.  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "MSBuild project build output verbosity" setting.  Jack it up to "Normal" so you can see the build command.

Comment: I thought that the compiler warning was allowing for the possibility that the signature that uses NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler instead of EventRegistrationToken was valid.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I thought that the compiler warning was allowing for the possibility that the signature that uses NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler instead of EventRegistrationToken was valid. I rewrote the sample to create a class library (removing all Console possibilities) with the same result.  I have my compiler settings at Normal for both verbosity levels, and I tried pasting the CSC statement from VS into my compile.cmd file, only removing some references to temporary .cs files that were empty anyway and I expected that to work, but no joy. Not sure where to go next.